# Button outside of ScreenManager to control ScreenManager screen loading

Tags: navigation, kivy

I've been able to get this example to load ([switch screenmanager inside layout](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41337143/switch-screenmanager-inside-layout))

What I'm unclear on is how to get the buttons at the very bottom of the kv file to load a screen in the ScreenManager since they are outside  the scope of the SM.

At the bottom of the above post, the originator posted 'fixed' example code but the buttons at the bottom don't appear to have any functionality.

I'm use to the following syntax working in a standard ScreenManager layout but in this context I'm getting the error below and am lost:

> ```
> Button:
>     text: 'New Session'
>     on_press: root.manager.current = 'newSession'
>
> AttributeError: 'AllScreen' object has no attribute 'manager'
> ```

The example I'm referencing above seems to do exactly what I'm hoping to achieve... a button menu area defined once that controls the screen display of SM. I hope to avoid defining a lot of redundant button code in the kivy file for each desired screen.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can add an `id` to the `ScreenManagement` instance within the `ClassAllScreen` rule in the `kv`, and use that `id` in the `Button` rule:

```
<ClassAllScreen>:
    orientation:'vertical'
    ScreenManagement:
        id: manager
    BoxLayout:
    .
    .
    .
        Button:
            text: 'New Session'
            on_press: manager.current = 'newSession'
```

Comment: Thank you for providing clarification... I was getting stuck where scope of context was for the reference. That solved my issue and I'm back to making progress.